# Sagemaker Studio Lab How do I configure AWS for running in Sagemaker Studio Lab?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently trying to use some AWS Built-In algorithms in the new  Sagemaker Studio Lab. In order to do so, I need to configure my AWS profile to get my execution role and region etc.
This is the current message

`ValueError: Must setup local AWS configuration with a region supported by SageMaker.`

Locally I am using credentials file for the configuration of the AWS CLI, how can I do this in Sagemaker Studio Lab?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Found the solution

Comment: Everything is documented in this Jupyter Notebook
https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/blob/main/connect-to-aws/Access_AWS_from_Studio_Lab.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for looking at Studio Lab! As has been mentioned in the above comments, we have a sample walkthrough notebook of configuring the aws cli and boto3 in Studio Lab here.

- https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/blob/main/connect-to-aws/Access_AWS_from_Studio_Lab.ipynb

Please just remember to NEVER EVER EVER share your access or secret key information on GitHub. If you use a notebook to write those files, just delete that cell immediately after executing it.

Cheers!